# Difference b/w <context-param> and <init-param>

Tags: java, servlets, deployment-descriptor, init-parameters

DD elements `<context-param>` and `<init-param>` both can be retrieved by the `getInitParameter()` method, in the servlet code.

Now the question is, how does it differentiate `<context-param>` and `<init-param>`?

Comment: I don't know why, but I agree that it is confusing and annoying.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Servlet **init parameters** are for a single servlet only. Nothing outside that servlet can access that. It is declared inside the `<servlet>` tag of Deployment Descriptor, on the other hand **context init parameter** is for the entire web application. Any servlet or JSP in that web application can access **context init parameter**. **Context parameters** are declared in a tag `<context-param>` directly inside the `<web-app>` tag.

The methods for accessing **context init parameter** is

```
getServletContext().getInitParameter("name");
```

whereas the method for accessing **servlet init parameter** is

```
getServletConfig().getInitParameter("name");
```

Answer (score 2):

As explained by [Adeel Ansari, here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2070046/42769), it depends on what object are you invoking the method `getInitParameter()` in the servlet code.

All servlets extends from and hence are instance of `GenericServlet`.

.

DD elements `<context-param>` can be retrieved by:

```
ServletContext context = this.getServletContext();
String paramValue = context.getInitParamter("paramName");
```

.

DD elements `<init-param>` both can be retrieved by:

```
ServletConfig config = this.getServletConfig();
String paramValue = config.getInitParamter("paramName");
```

Also note that since `GenericServlet` class implements `ServletConfig` interface, your servlet class is also ServletConfig (implies `this = this.getServletConfig()` ). Hence you can also get DD elements `<init-param>` directly by:

```
String paramValue = this.getInitParamter("paramName");
```

.

You can try this by having same param-name in both DD elements with different values and then print it in your servlet.