# How to get ServeletConfig in Jersey Provider?

Tags: servlets, jersey, provider, servletconfig

So I have a Jersey REST service and I need to get access to a ServletConfig so that I can pull a param out of the web.xml. I can use @Context to wire one in but I don't think it will get me the params I need. Only the ones in the ServletContext.

Any ideas? I'm new to Jersey and this Provider isn't a Servelet.  Perhaps I should start with trying to retrieve the servelet?

Comment: @Context will do the work for you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17324460/1840774

Answer (score 2):

@Context: annotation can be used to inject the following classes

1. HttpServletRequest
2. HttpServletResponse
3. ServletContext
4. ServletConfig
5. WebConfig.

onto a root resource, provider and Application classes.

[Java Doc of Servlet Container](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer.html)

Comment: ACK! It does all 5?? That is unusual... and awesome. :-)

Comment: What the dang thing is good for should be in the annotation JavaDocs but it ain't. :-|  It seems their docs leave something to be desired. At the link you provided, I shouldn't be seeing this as if it were regular text without any link either: (@link PackagesResourceConfig#PROPERTY_PACKAGES}