# Spring : Need for the contextConfigLocation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

In `web.xml` we have context parameter set named `contextConfigLocation` and defined as shown in the below code:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Also the same parameter is set in the Dispatch Servlet as shown below

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

What is the difference between these two `contextConfigLocation`s ?

Comment: You can take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069902/dd-elements-context-param-and-init-param-both-use-the-getinitparameter-me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- contextConfigLocation in context-param gets Loaded, when We start Our
  Web Container or server
- It usually has DAOImpl, Service, Singleton, Datasource
  Helper Objects etc , those objects We want to be ready before hand so that they can be used

---

- contextConfigLocation in init-param is specific to that DispatcherServlet Only and gets Loaded as soon as Servlet Starts up which may be Lazily loaded i.e on first call to Servlet, if load-on-startup is not a positive value for that servlet.
- This means, Beans defined here could be possibly created later.  It usually contains Controller Beans etc

---

- Beans defined in context-param ContextXml are visible to Beans defined
  in init-param ContextXml
- But the Beans defined in init-param are not visible to context-param
  context Beans
- So @Controller Bean is usually defined in ChildApplicationContext while @Service is a part of RootApplicationContext
- This means @Controller cannot be injected in @Service
  While as we easily can easily inject @Service Bean in @Controller

---

> So basically we control Visibility (not scope ) of Beans by having
>   different context-config files

Answer (score 2):

The fist setting applies globally, whilst second setting is private and exclusive to the "spring" servlet.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of contexts:

Root context (Super)

Own (child) servlet context (Sub)

As generic application contexts, web application contexts are hierarchical. There is a single root context per application, while each servlet in the application (including a dispatcher servlet in the MVC framework) has its own child context.